# Projections: Beppo Levi

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider projections:
$$P_\lambda\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad P_\lambda^2=P_\lambda=P_\lambda^*$$

And directed indices:
$$\forall\lambda,\lambda'\in\Lambda\exists\lambda_0\in\Lambda:\quad \lambda,\lambda'\leq\lambda_0$$

Suppose monotony:
$$\lambda\leq\lambda'\implies P_\lambda\leq P_{\lambda'}$$

Denote for readability:
$$\mathcal{R}:=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mathcal{R}P_\lambda=\bigg\langle\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mathcal{R}P_\lambda\bigg\rangle$$

> Then strongly one has:
>   $$1_\overline{\mathcal{R}}\varphi=\lim_\lambda P_\lambda\varphi\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H})$$

How can I prove this?

*(Operator-theoretic proof?)*

Comment: What does Beppo Levi (without the hyphen, as that is the first name and last name, respectively, of a guy) have to do with this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thanks for the hint. I thought monotone convergence goes under the name Beppo Levi. But this is sort of a generalization on projections. Soo..

Comment: I want not giving a hint! I was just asking why you mentioned Levi in the title of the question and not at all in the actual question, and observing that you wrote his name incorrectly.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Yes and I appreciate that you clarified the name issue. :) About the other thing, I meant it seems reasonable to give the thread that title because of this. It should just give a quick hint on what this thread is about. The details then are in the thread itself and made precise - without any name.

Comment: @Admins: I'm sorry. :S I noticed I had to roll back my last edit as I couldn't adapt the answer then. That was a little stupid as I thought I could make it more readable (for me). Hope you don't mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it...*

**Limit Projection**

By orthogonality one has:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{R}^\perp\implies\varphi\in\mathcal{R}_\lambda^\perp\quad(\lambda\in\Lambda)$$

So one obtains:
$$\|P_\lambda\varphi-0\|=\|0-0\|=0\stackrel{\lambda}{\to}0$$

By monotony one has:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{R}\implies\varphi\in\mathcal{R}_\lambda\quad(\lambda\geq\lambda_\varphi)$$

So one obtains:
$$\|P_\lambda\varphi-\varphi\|=\|\varphi-\varphi\|=0\stackrel{\lambda}{\to}0$$

This extends to closure as:
$$\|P_\lambda\|_{\lambda\in\Lambda}=\sup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\|P_\lambda\|=1<\infty$$

Concluding limit projection.

**Limit Range**

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Consider the projections:
$$P_n:=1-R^nL^n:\quad P_n\leq P_{n+1}$$

But for the limit range:
$$\mathcal{R}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal{R}P_n:\quad \mathcal{R}=\ell^2_0(\mathbb{N})\neq\ell^2(\mathbb{N})=\overline{\mathcal{R}}$$

Concluding limit range.