# Dense Subspaces: Intersection

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Hilbert Space: $\mathcal{H}$

Dense Subspaces:
$$\mathcal{D},\mathcal{D}'\leq\mathcal{H}:\quad\overline{\mathcal{D}},\overline{\mathcal{D}'}=\mathcal{H}\not\Rightarrow\mathcal{D}\cap\mathcal{D}'\neq\{0\}$$
*(Counterexample?)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}=L^2[0,1]$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the subspace of polynomials on $[0,1]$. Let $\mathcal{D}'$ be the subspace generated by $\{ \sin(n\pi x) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Both are dense, and they have nothing in common except the $0$ vector.

Comment: Easy peasy. Thanks alot!! :)

Comment: @Freeze_S : For being so easy, I sure spent a lot of time thinking about it. :)

Comment: Really?? But still your examples are amazing, like really enlightening and intuitive. I really love them!! :)

Comment: Hey you soon reach the 30k. :D

Answer (score -1):

What about subspaces $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$  in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yeah I also thought about them, too. Is it possible to construct a *complex* and *separable* Hilbert space?

Comment: $D=\{q_1+q_2 i; q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb Q \}$ and $D'=\{p_1+p_2 i; p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \}$

Comment: Still it fails to be *complex* resp. they fail to be *subspaces*.

Comment: Besides the *complex* Hilbert space must be at least infinite dimensional for possible counterexamples.

Comment: Mea culpa, I overview the "subspace" assumption. I'll edit my answer as comment would be too long.

Comment: No worries. ;) Please go ahead.

Comment: Anyway can you create a subspace $D \subset \mathcal H$, if $\mathcal H$ is separable Hilbert such that $\overline D=\mathcal H$ and $D \neq \mathcal H$?

Comment: **Prenote: This is (too) technical!** I was thinking about $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. I take $\mathcal{D}=\langle\{1_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\rangle$. I regard $1_\infty:=(1,\frac12,\frac{1}{4},\ldots)$. Then I was thinking about Gram-Schmidt $\mathcal{D}'=\langle\mathbb{G}\{1_n+1_\infty:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\rangle$.

Comment: I just found the mistake in my proof, I'll try to get back to this in the evening

Comment: Alright, no hurry! Besides, thanks for helping me out!!