# $(U\cap W)^\perp = U^\perp + W^\perp$ in metric vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

I'm currently working my way through Roman *Advanced Linear Algebra* chapter 11 and am getting caught up on 2(b).

> Let $U,W$ be subspaces of a metric vector space.
> Prove that $(U\cap W)^\perp = U^\perp + W^\perp$.

I've proven that $U^\perp + W^\perp \subseteq (U\cap W)^\perp$, but I'm struggling to prove the other way around. Every proof I've found so far on StackExchange requires $U^{\perp\perp} = U$ which doesn't hold necessarily hold in a metric vector space, as $U \subseteq U^{\perp\perp}$ (equality holding when $V$ is non-singular, which is not guaranteed). Could anyone help me here? I've tried to use similar proof patterns as other problems, but none of them have worked in extending to metric vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Side note: the term "metric vector space" is, as far as I know, not in extremely widespread use and might even be peculiar to the Roman textbook.

For readers who do not have this text, Roman defines a "metric vector space" to be a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ equipped with an $F$-valued bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: V \times V \to F$ that is *either* symmetric (i.e., satisfying $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $V$), or skew-symmetric (satisfying $\langle x, y \rangle = -\langle y, x \rangle$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $V$), or what Roman calls "alternating" (satisfying $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$ in $V$).  This definition occurs on pp. 259-260 of the third edition of the Springer GTM text.  For $U$ a subspace of a "metric vector space" $V$, Roman defines $U^{\perp} = \{v \in V: \text{$\langle v, u \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in U$}\}$ in the usual way.  This definition occurs on p. 265 of the text, where here and elsewhere I again refer to the pagination of the third edition of the Springer GTM text.

Thus Roman's notion of "metric vector space" includes any example of what a lot of books and Wikipedia would refer to as a real "inner product space" (i.e., a real vector space equipped with a symmetric and positive-definite bilinear form), but his notion of "metric vector space" includes other stuff, too, while also not generally including complex inner product spaces (whose bilinear forms are conjugate-symmetric).  Roman discusses inner product spaces in a separate chapter of his text, and indeed, makes a remark similar to this one on p. 260 of his discussion of "metric vector spaces."

In complete generality, the equality
$$
(U \cap W)^{\perp} = U^{\perp} + W^{\perp}
$$
for subspaces $U, W$ of a common metric space $V$ may not hold.  As you observe in your question, the inclusion $U^{\perp} + W^{\perp} \subseteq (U \cap W)^{\perp}$ *does* hold in general, so the potential problems arise only with the other inclusion.

As one family of examples, there are infinite-dimensional real inner product spaces $V$ having dense subspaces $U$ and $W$ with trivial intersection.  See e.g. [Dense subspaces of Hilbert space with trivial intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078481/dense-subspaces-of-hilbert-space-with-trivial-intersection) and [Dense Subspaces: Intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741923/dense-subspaces-intersection) for examples (although neither post expressly specifies real scalars, you can take the $L^2$ spaces in both posts to be real $L^2$ spaces).  And in this situation we have $(U \cap W)^{\perp} = \{0\}^{\perp} = V$ while $U^{\perp} + W^{\perp} = \{0\} + \{0\} = \{0\}$, so that the inclusion $U^{\perp} + W^{\perp} \subsetneq (U \cap W)^{\perp}$ is as proper as it is possible to get.

You note in your question that some arguments found elsewhere on MSE use the equality $(U^{\perp})^{\perp} = U$ in a crucial place.  You very correctly note that this equality is *not* an identity that holds for all subspaces $U$ of all metric vector spaces.  This equality *does* hold, however, for *finite dimensional* metric vector spaces (the usual argument uses an inclusion and an equality of the finite dimension to deduce an equality of the spaces).  Correspondingly, Roman states (in the second sentence of Chapter 11, p. 259):

> Unless otherwise mentioned, all vector spaces are assumed to be finite-dimensional

i.e., he has a blanket assumption allowing those arguments given elsewhere on MSE to work, or at least to have a chance of working.  (It's definitely worth doublechecking whether any argument you find on MSE, which may have been given only for the case of a real or complex inner product, still works in the case of a general "metric vector space.")

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on terminology. It's kind of annoying he does that. That said, could you elaborate on the $U = U^\perp$ for finite dimensional ones? Cause, from what I understand, it would only work if $V$ itself was nonsingular (as per Theorem 11.8(2) on page  270). I still can't see how it would hold if $V$ wasn't nonsingular as, assuming $U$ was non-singular, we'd have $U^\perp = \{0,x\}$ where $x \perp V$, and then $U^{\perp\perp} = V$.