# Density of $V \cap W$ in $W$ for a closed subspace $W$ of a completion of a pre-Hilbert space $V$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

(Note: I asked a [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363679/density-of-v-cap-w-in-w-for-a-subspace-w-of-a-completion-of-a-pre-hilbert), only after which I realized that I had asked something other than what I had in mind, so I'm posting what I truly intended to ask here.)

I am interested in density of $V \cap W$ in $W$ for a *closed* subspace $W$ of a completion of a pre-Hilbert space $V$.  Does there exist $W$ for which $V \cap W$ is not dense in $W$?  If so, what are $W$ for which $V\cap W$ *is* dense in $W$?

Comment: A subspace of codimension 1 is either dense or else is closed.

Comment: Take a look at $V=c_0(\Bbb N)\subset \ell^2(\Bbb N)$. Then let $W$ be the subspace of $\ell^2$ generated by the sequence $2^{-n}$, which is $1$-dimesnional and hence closed. However $V\cap W=\emptyset$.