# Orthogonal complement of subspaces of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a complex, infinite dimensional, separable Hilbert space

Let $\{h1_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $H$

Let $\{h2_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $H$

Let $V1=\operatorname{Span}(\{h1_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}})$

Let $V2=\operatorname{Span}(\{h2_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}})$

We know that $\{h1_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \cap \{h2_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent algebraically (for finite linear combinations)

Let $U1=\overline{V1}$

Let $U2=\overline{V2}$

Let $W= U1 \cap U2$

Let $W1$ be the orthogonal complement of subspace $W$ of the space $U1$

Let $W2$ be the orthogonal complement of subspace $W$ of the space $U2$

My questions:

Is it true that

$V1 \subset W1$ and $V2 \subset W2$

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post questions. The new information could easily have been edited into the old question. Speaking of which, should it be the intersection of the sequences, or the *union* of the sequences, that happens to be linearly independent? The intersection could be empty, while keeping $V1 = V2$.

Comment: Also, here's a comment I was going to make under the old post: No, not in general. The subspaces $V1$ and $V2$ could easily be dense (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741923/dense-subspaces-intersection)), which would make $W = H$ and $W1, W2$ trivial.

Comment: @TheoBendit you are right but at once i did't know what were the parts to be corrected, exuse me

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for your answer

Comment: It's no problem; just something to keep in mind in future. If you think your question is not up to scratch once you've posted it, another possibility is to delete it, edit it while it's deleted, then undelete it. We just don't like it when people delete their question and repost it, because it wasn't answered immediately, or was received poorly. Neither was the case for your deleted question, but we discourage the practice nonetheless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dense Subspaces: Intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741923/dense-subspaces-intersection) (If my comment answers your question, then let's just mark the question as a duplicate.)

Comment: @TheoBendit You are right in both things, both for the deletion and in the answer to my question, the counterexample is right