# the orthogonal complement intersection of sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{C_\gamma\}$ be a net of subsets of a Hilbert space(or some other spaces). Do we have 
$$(\wedge_\gamma C_\gamma )^\perp = \vee_\gamma  C_\gamma ^\perp?$$
It is known that
it works when $\{C_\gamma\}$ is a sequence of sets.

Comment: You may have a look into: [Hilbert vs. De Morgan](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1408559/79762)

Comment: @Freeze_S  Thx, gay!

Comment: You're welcome! Gay?

Comment: @Freeze_S  sorry! GUY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $\wedge_\gamma C_\gamma $ is the intersection, ie the inf, and $\vee_\gamma  C_\gamma ^\perp$ is the sup, ie the smallest closed subspace containing each $C_\gamma^\perp$, then yes. (The reason I'm not entirely sure is that this has nothing to do with nets, everything is the same for a *family* $C_\gamma$, directed or not.)

Since $C_\gamma^\perp$ is orthogonal to $C_\gamma$ it is orthogonal to the intersection of the $C_\gamma$. So $$C_\gamma^\perp\subset (\wedge_\gamma C_\gamma )^\perp, $$and since the right side is a closed subspace, the definition of $\vee$ shows that$$\vee_\gamma C_\gamma^\perp\subset (\wedge_\gamma C_\gamma )^\perp.$$

For the other inclusion we need only show that $$(\vee_\gamma C_\gamma^\perp)^\perp\subset\wedge_\gamma C_\gamma.$$But this is clear: If $x$ is orthogonal to $\vee_\gamma C_\gamma^\perp$ then $x$ is orthogonal to $C_\gamma^\perp$, so $x\in C_\gamma$.

Comment: It is very helpful! Wikipedia just has the case of sequence.THX!